# Unable to view UPnP Responses over network

Tags: wireshark, upnp

I am using wireshark. I am trying to view UPnP responses from Belkin Wemo devices on my network. The wemo app sends out a discovery packet (using SSDP) to a multicast address, which you can see in the screenshot below. I should also see responses via http/1.1, but I don't. The app gets back a response, but its unclear to me how as I don't see the packets.

[image: Discovery Packets]

How can I see the UPnP responses?

As a note, I do see a LLC response from the wemo devices, but this doesn't provide a LOCATION.

Comment: @guest-vm if I disable 802.11 monitor mode, how will I capture the packets?

Comment: @guest-vm - Wireshark on OSX, and the wemo app on my iPhone. The only packets I see are `urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1`, which is for search. I need to hunt down the notify sent from the wemo.

Comment: On your iPhone, stop wifi & wemo app, then restart both. During this process, does wireshark capture any packet with `urn:Belkin:device:controllee:1`? And if you change filter to "http", do you see any request to your Wemo device which could reveal the LOCATION header in the SSDP response?

Comment: Please clarify if you can capture and decrypt http traffic of web browser of iPhone from your OSX. Try a non-https site for clarity.

Comment: @guest-vm - Sorry, got pulled away - I think you are correct about iphone encrypting the data, I can see other broadcasts from other devices. For example by Unifi router sends out messages in clear text. I might be chasing a white rabbit here. Make you comment about the `decrypt http traffic of web browser of iPhone from your OSX` has the answer...

Comment: This is not a rabbit hole. Final advice: 1. in wireshark, add `wpa-pwd:password:ssid` to IEEE 802.11 in Preferences 2. disable wifi of iphone, start capturing in wireshark, re-enable wifi of iphone, filter by "eapol", make sure you get all 4 handshake packets 3. start web browser/wemo app and inspect packet by changing filter to "http"/"ssdp" 4. if above steps don't work, then 802.11 monitor mode is at fault. visit [Ask Wireshark](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/) for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPA2 use different keys for each device and session[[1]](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11). You need to capture EAPOL handshake of your iOS, not OSX, so as to decrypt traffic of iOS.

See these[[2]](http://mattenoble.com/2013/08/07/wemo-hacking/)[[3]](https://objectpartners.com/2014/03/25/a-groovy-time-with-upnp-and-wemo/) for hints of expected UPnP traffic of a Wemo Switch.
Search Type for other Wemo devices taken from [wemo-client](https://github.com/timonreinhard/wemo-client):

```
Wemo.DEVICE_TYPE = {
  Bridge: 'urn:Belkin:device:bridge:1',
  Switch: 'urn:Belkin:device:controllee:1',
  Motion: 'urn:Belkin:device:sensor:1',
  Maker: 'urn:Belkin:device:Maker:1',
  Insight: 'urn:Belkin:device:insight:1',
  LightSwitch: 'urn:Belkin:device:lightswitch:1',
  Dimmer: 'urn:Belkin:device:dimmer:1',
  Humidifier: 'urn:Belkin:device:Humidifier:1',
  HeaterB: 'urn:Belkin:device:HeaterB:1'
};
```